# Bootstrap progress bar with icons

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, progress-bar

I need to make progress bar with icons, or at least something that looks like that to me:
[image]

So far I went with this solution:

```html
<div class="d-block w-100">
  <div class="progress">
    <i class="bi bi-arrow-down-circle"></i>
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    <i class="bi bi-arrow-down-circle"></i>
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    <i class="bi bi-arrow-down-circle"></i>
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    <i class="bi bi-arrow-down-circle"></i>
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    <i class="bi bi-arrow-down-circle"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I think there has to be better solution. Any advice is welcomed.
PS: Don't mind the icons.

Answer (score 0):

Since bootstrap doesn't have progress/stepper feature, you need to use some third party library to achieve this.

Visit the below link to know how stepper works and they have sample code also, use it and customize

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b4/jquery/components/stepper/